# Kubectl patch json format on windows: syntax error

Tags: json, windows, kubernetes, patch

> kubectl patch sts web -p '{"spec":{"replicas":3}}'

```
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal
string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

Tried to exchange "double quote" with "single quote", not working.

> kubectl patch sts web -p "{'spec':{'replicas':3}}"

```
Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\''
looking for beginning of object key string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using json, you need to take cautions while using spaces as well, if you forgot to add or add an extra space the json string which you pass as an argument to the command will fail the syntax requirements.

In the command provided, though you have tried replacing single quotes with double quotes the actual error is caused because of not providing spaces at required places. If you go through this [**reference document**](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/) they have given spaces after **spec** and **replica**. Try following the same and your syntax error will get resolved. I have just added spaces in the command you are using as per the above reference.

> kubectl patch sts web -p '{"spec" :{"replicas" :3}}'

Comment: Tried your command kubectl patch sts web -p '{"spec" :{"replicas" :3}}'. error: unable to parse "'{spec": yaml: found unexpected end of stream. Is it on windows?

Comment: @eastwater I think as mentioned [here](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask/issues/36) I think you need to use escape stings. Try this command and see once

kubectl patch sts web -p "{\"spec\" :{\"replicas\" :3}}"

Comment: @eastwater is your issue resolved..? revert back if your still facing some issues..

Comment: escape with double quotes: works.